# Misunderstanding numpy.vectorize

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, function, vectorization

I want to apply a function to each row in a vector. Even on a simple example like the one below I cant get it to work.

I make a function that takes two vectors and applies the dot product to them.

```
import numpy as np


def func(x,y):
    return np.dot(x,y)

y=np.array([0, 1, 2])
x=np.array([0, 1, 2])

print(func(x,y))
```

Of course the output is 5. Now I want to plug in multiple vectors x, and get a solution back for each one. I dont want to use a for loop, so I tried using the vectorize function. For instance below I define X=(x1,x2,x3) and I want the output func(X,y)=(func(x1,y), func(x2,y), func(x3,y)).  Why doesn't the following code do that:

```
import numpy as np


def func(x,y):
    return np.dot(x,y)

y=np.array([0, 1 , 2])
X=np.array([[0,0,0], [1,1,1], [2,2,2]])


vfunc=np.vectorize(func)
print(vfunc(X,y))
```

Comment: Not an actual answer: But in the vectorize function it is said, "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop." So you could also use a python one-line for loop

Comment: I am doing that now, but think vectorize is more compact.

Comment: Can you print out what output you are getting? `Vfunc(X, y)` should be giving you `np.array([vfunc(X[0], y), vfunc(X[1], y), vfunc(X[2], y)]`. Edit: Seems like `vfunc(X[0], y)` is giving a vector of size (3,) as output, instead of a scalar.

Comment: `x` is a (3,3) array.  `vectorize` passes scalar values to your function, not rows.  reread its docs. Beware of compactness for its own sake.

Answer (score 1):

The first trick to do is to **exclude** *y* argument (it is a fixed value
for all rows from *x*).

The second trick is to pass the **signature**: Both arguments are arrays and
the result is a scalar.

So, to vectorize your function, run:

```
vfunc = np.vectorize(func, excluded=['y'], signature='(n),(n)->()')
```

Then, when you call `vfunc(X,y)`, you will get:

```
array([0, 3, 6])
```

Comment: `excluded=['y']` isn't actually doing anything here, since you're not passing `y` by keyword.

Comment: You're right. *excluded* is not needed.

Comment: signature makes vectorize even slower.